# DependencyService in Multiplatform library project?

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget, visual-studio-mac

I am trying to set up DependencyService to call platform  specific code in a [Multiplatform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/nuget-multiplatform-libraries/platform-specific) project.

[image]

When calling `Dependency.Get<IService>()` in the Shared project I get null.

The Service inside iOS does not seem to register.

I have tried to register it like this: `[assembly: Dependency(typeof(Service))]`- on top of the namespace declaration inside the iOS project. Which I have gotten to work inside a Xamarin.Forms project. And I have also tried to call `DependencyService.Register<Service>();` inside a Init method in the iOS project - calling it from a Xamarin.Forms iOS project in AppDelegate - made for testing the library.

The `Shared` project and `iOS` project does not seem to share the same `DependencyService`.

How can I call platform specific code in the iOS project from the Shared project with DependencyService?

**Edit**

I am getting `System.PlatformNotSupportedException` when working in visual studio on windows - trying to use DependencyService inside a net standard library project. Could it be that visual studio for mac simply doesn't throw error and returns null instead?

Comment: Why did you still use share project ? I suggest you could use XF . And you can share a sample which contains the issue so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I need to create a `NuGet` I can't do that with a XF project?

Comment: Yes - working on it

Comment: https://github.com/Lelelo1/DependencyServiceIssue

Comment: The issue also exists when trying to call platform specific code from .Net Standard Library project

Comment: @lolelo can you please describe what you are trying to do?

Comment: @lawiluk I am trying to create a custom control that can be created to a NuGet. It needs platform specific implementation as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve the problem by removing Shared project and changing

```
MyMutliplatformLibraryProject.Run.Test();
```

to

```
MyXamarinFormsProject.Run.Test();
```

If you are trying to create a Nuget with custom controls you can follow [this tutorial how to do it](https://lukaszlawicki.pl/lets-make-a-net-standard-package-logbook-2/).

With .NET standard you don't need to have a shared project. The only obstacle I can see that you are targeting multiple targets. Why don't you start simple and later adjust it?

Long story short. Let's assume you want a NuGet for Xamarin.Forms app, with iOS & Android. You simply need .NET standard, iOS & Android dll. That's all. Later you can create a package with nuspec

Comment: The `MyXamarinFormsProject.Run.Test()` was just for testing DependencyService. And it works in a Xamarin.Forms project. However it does not work from Shared in Multiplatform project nor from a Net Standard project. Using iOS/Android .dll only, I do not get access to renderers found in `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS`/`Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android` namespaces.

Comment: You don't need a Shared project at all. Simply try from scratch and you will see it. Just configure your nuspec file correctly and you will have access to everything you need. Trust me on this

Comment: The Shared is created from creating a Multiplatform project:`Multiplatform` -> `platform-specific`.

Comment: Is `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android` namespaces supposed to be accessible after adding their respective dll file?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that so let me answer it in a differently: your nuget should be installed to all projects: Core, iOS, Android. In core, you should be able to access your control & in platform projects, you should be able to access renderers

Comment: Adding iOS & Android dll to a Net standard library don't let me access any renderers. Creating iOS/Android libs - these can't be accessed from the .Net Standard lib, (neither with DependencyService nor CustomRenderers).