# How to multitarget in Xamarin.Forms with Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget, visual-studio-mac

I started out creating a `.NET Standard Library` that I intended to make a `NuGet` of - but came to find that I also needed platform-specific functionality.

So, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55291602/how-does-one-create-a-project-to-create-a-nuget-package-for-xamarin-forms-suppor) stack overflow question - which indicated I could use a `Multiplatform Library`template instead. But here I encountered a [problem with DependencyService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57073400/dependencyservice-in-multiplatform-library-project) - and a problem with `Custom Renderer` - effectively meaning that there was no way for the non-platform-specific to communicate with platform-specific code in the library.

I also tried to edit the csproj file, examples: [A](https://github.com/Cheesebaron/MultiTargetSample/blob/master/MultiTargetLib/MultiTargetLib.csproj), [B](https://medium.com/corrado-cavalli/net-standard-and-multi-targeting-e96920b3fcfe), [C](https://montemagno.com/converting-xamarin-libraries-to-sdk-style-multi-targeted-projects/). And by using the following csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras/2.0.29">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;Xamarin.ios10</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Forms" Version="4.1.0.581479" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

... the following solution is generated:

[image]

But in `Class1` the `Xamarin.iOS` nor `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS` can be accessed in `Visual Studio for Mac`. And I recently checked and could see that it worked in `Visual Studio` on windows - using the same csproj.

Is there any way to multitarget in `Visual Studio for Mac`?

---

**Edit 1**:
I found an [issue](https://github.com/onovotny/MSBuildSdkExtras/issues/9) on `MSBuild.Sdk.Extras` on GitHub leading to this [post](https://oren.codes/2017/08/29/use-all-tfms-with-sdk-style-projects-in-visual-studio-for-mac/). It seems a certain extension can be installed called `DotNetCoreSupportAnyTargetFramework.DotNetCoreSupportAnyTargetFramework_1.0`. But it won't be installed correctly in VSfM 8.1.5:

[image]

Trying it out in older VSfM I can't open project or create new ones - so I can't test to see if the extension works. It could be related to the following error message:

[image]

that shows when opening the old VSfM.

---

**Edit 2:** After changing the order the target frameworks are given in - placing `Xamarin.ios10` first - the Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS became accessible - as mentioned by Matt Ward.

However I can't add reference to the NetStandard Library to a Xamarin.Forms project to actually test the library:

[image]

And switching back to having netstandard placed first:

> Projects/MyStandardLibrary/MyStandardLibrary/MyButtonRender.cs(12,12): Error CS0246: The type or namespace name'ExportRendererAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246) (MyStandardLibrary) etc.

Comment: Could you have a try with `unload` and `reload` by right cliking Solution ?

Comment: There no option to reload the solution. But I can unload - load the project. It does not help.

Comment: Please note that the DotNetCoreSupportAnyTargetFramework addin is not needed in Visual Studio for Mac since version 7.4.

Comment: What does `But in Class1 the Xamarin.iOS nor Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS can be accessed in Visual Studio for Mac` mean? By access are you talking about selecting that framework in the text editor? That is not yet supported. Only workaround would be to edit the .csproj and change the order of the target frameworks. Only the first one is currently used in the text editor.

Comment: @Matt Ward. Yes that was it! Changing `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;Xamarin.ios10</TargetFrameworks>` to `<TargetFrameworks>Xamarin.ios10;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>` let me access Xamarin.iOS stuff.

Comment: Hopefully multi-targeting support in the text editor will be included in Visual Studio for Mac 8.3 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/mac-roadmap#2019-q3-july-september

Comment: @Matt Ward. Aren't the existing Multplatform library project template supposed to be used though - creating NuGets from multi target library? As I mentioned in the question I have had problems with them as well though.

Comment: Multiplatform library project is a way to create a NuGet package. Each project in the Multiplatform library solution have a single target framework. They are not multi-target framework projects themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current release of Visual Studio for Mac, v8.2, does not support Multi-Targeting.

According to the [Visual Studio for Mac Roadmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/productinfo/mac-roadmap?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-bramin), Multi-Targeting support will be available in Visual Studio for Mac v8.3:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/productinfo/mac-roadmap#2019-q3-july-september](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/productinfo/mac-roadmap?WT.mc_id=none-stackoverflow-bramin#2019-q3-july-september)

Edit: You can follow the team's progress on adding Multi Targeting support here: https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/pull/7848

Comment: I found it bit confusing because there is a template: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/nuget-multiplatform-libraries/?tabs=macos which supposedly seem to do it. But as I stated in the question it does not seem to function properly.

Comment: @lolelo Goo catch - it looks like the templates were added a bit prematurely. In the answer, I added a link to the PR for Multi-Targeting support. It looks like the team is getting close!